# Is Weapon Focus (spell) a valid option?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats

We know that Weapon Focus (touch) and Weapon Focus (ray) are valid options. But is Weapon Focus (spell) a valid option? Is there any concrete evidence that it is or is not valid?

Personally, I do not believe it's valid because spells are not weapons, but I've encountered individuals who argue that spells are considered weapons under certain circumstances.

Comment: I answered the question below, since the answer doesn't really depend on it, but for clarification; what would a focus of "spell" apply to?

Comment: So, you want a feat that has the properties of two feats without any added limitation?  No.  Use two spell slots.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Only for rays and weapon-like spells

[Rays](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Aiming-a-Spell) are considered weapon attacks, and you are allowed to pick Weapon Focus, Weapon Specialization and Improved Critical with ray attacks, as shown in this [FAQ item](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9nef)):

> *Weapon Specialization: Can you take Weapon Specialization (ray) or Improved Critical (ray) as feats? How about Weapon Specialization (bomb) or Improved Critical (bomb)?*
>
> All four of those are valid choices.
>
> Note that Weapon Specialization (ray) only adds to hit point damage caused by a ray attack that would normally deal hit point damage; it doesn't increase ability score damage or drain (such as the Dexterity drain from polar ray), penalties to ability scores (such as from ray of enfeeblement) or drain, negative levels (such as from enervation), or other damage or penalties from rays.

Another [FAQ on the same subject](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9oag) also adds this:

> *Ray: Do rays count as weapons for the purpose of spells and effects that affect weapons?*
>
> Yes. (See also this FAQ item for a similar question about rays and weapon feats.)
>
> For example, a bard's inspire courage says it affects "weapon damage rolls," which is worded that way so don't try to add the bonus to a spell like fireball. However, rays are treated as weapons, whether they're from spells, a monster ability, a class ability, or some other source, so the inspire courage bonus applies to ray attack rolls and ray damage rolls.
>
> The same rule applies to **weapon-like spells such as flame blade, mage's sword, and spiritual weapon**--effects that affect weapons work on these spells.

Meaning that if you have *Weapon Focus (Scimitar)*, you can apply that to your [Flame Blade](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/flame-blade/) weapon-like spell attacks, but you cannot take *Weapon Focus (Fireball)*.

Ranged touch attacks and rays are not exactly the same thing, as shown in [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/63551/21153), so keep that in mind.

Comment: So spells themselves would not be valid, but spell effects that are considered weapons would be?

Answer (score 1):

### The feat only lists "Ray" as an option for spell attacks

The Weapon Focus feat (found at http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/feats.html#weapon-focus) specifically lists what options it has available. They are:

- One type of weapon
- Grapple
- Unarmed Strike
- Ray attacks (for a spellcaster)

The feat fully describes itself, so these are the only options - "touch" is not one of them, and neither is "spell".

Even if "touch" were an option, it's unclear what a focus of "spells" would do, since almost all spell attacks use touch or rays (area spells generally don't use attacks).

Comment: Touch is a valid option because several official creatures have it as a feat.

Comment: @Cyrad; interesting, but ultimately irrelevant; the feat description is the primary source on itself, and it clearly does not allow "touch" as a focus. If there are monsters that have it, that just means they were poorly edited. Also, the only example I could find (Spectre) has an actual "Incorporeal Touch" natural weapon attack; that's a special case.

Answer (score 0):

RAW?  No.  It doesn't exist.

RAI?  No.  There is a Ray focus.  There is no Touch focus but I don't see a reason there couldn't be.  If there is no Touch focus then it means that RAI is that only Rays should get it.  If there is a Touch focus then the two types of spell that require an attack roll are already covered and you can't just create a feat that does what two feats do.

Common sense?  No.  If you don't roll to hit, there is no bonus for hitting them in just the right spot.  The RAI for most spells that aren't Rays is that the damage is area affect of distributed.

Comment: Weapon Focus (touch) is valid. Several official creatures in the bestiary have it.